# SQL Calendar and Count of Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, calendar

SQL Management Studio 18

I have a table with multiple columns, columns I need are Value, Date Opened, Date Closed.

I need to count cases by calendar date, # of cases opened, # of cases closed and the net. Cases do not open and close every day, hence the calendar needs to account for that.

Example Data

| Value | Date Opened | Date Closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 2023-01-26 00:00:00.0000 | 2023-01-31 00:00:00.0000 |
| 653421 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00.0000 | 2023-02-02 00:00:00.0000 |
| 987654 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00.0000 | NULL |

Desired Outcome

| Calendar Date | Count Open | Count Closed | Net |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-26 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-01-27 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-01-28 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-01-29 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-01-30 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-01-31 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-02-01 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 2023-02-02 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Check out https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/ to create your calendar table. You can then use a where clause to only get dates that are relevant to you. After you get that done, you can join an aggregate query of your data by CAST([Calendar Date] AS DATE) and COUNT(DISTINCT [Value]) to get your counts. I think with [Net], you can use LAG() to subtract from the previous row counts totaled https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-lag-function/.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common problem. The perfect solution would see you adding a calendar table to your database/server, but that's not always practical. You can simulate a basic one using a little CTE trick which makes use of the range actually present in your data:

```
;WITH BaseDates AS (
SELECT MIN(DateOpen) AS Date, CASE WHEN MAX(DateClosed)>MAX(DateOpen) THEN MAX(DateClosed) ELSE MAX(DateOpen) END AS mDate
  FROM @Example
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,Date), mDate
  FROM BaseDates
 WHERE date < mDate
)
```

| Date | mDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-26 | 2023-02-02 |
| 2023-01-27 | 2023-02-02 |
| 2023-01-28 | 2023-02-02 |
| 2023-01-29 | 2023-02-02 |
| 2023-01-30 | 2023-02-02 |
| 2023-01-31 | 2023-02-02 |
| 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-02 |
| 2023-02-02 | 2023-02-02 |

This gives us a complete list of all the dates in the range of your data.
We can then use it as the initial table to query to get your required results:

```
;WITH BaseDates AS (
SELECT MIN(DateOpen) AS Date, CASE WHEN MAX(DateClosed)>MAX(DateOpen) THEN MAX(DateClosed) ELSE MAX(DateOpen) END AS mDate
  FROM @Example
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,Date), mDate
  FROM BaseDates
 WHERE date < mDate
)

SELECT Date, OpenCnt, ClosedCnt, SUM(OpenCnt-ClosedCnt) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS NetCnt
  FROM (
SELECT Date, COUNT(DISTINCT o.Value) AS OpenCnt, COUNT(DISTINCT c.Value) AS ClosedCnt
  FROM BaseDates b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Example o
      ON b.Date = o.DateOpen
      AND (
               b.date < o.DateClosed 
            OR o.DateClosed IS NULL
          )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Example c
      ON b.Date = c.DateClosed
 GROUP BY b.Date
       ) a
```

Here we use the baseDates, and left outer join to the data on opens, and closeds for that day, counting the distinct values column.
We use that as a subquery and apply a windowed sum function over the top to give us a running total, ordered by date.

| Date | OpenCnt | ClosedCnt | NetCnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-26 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-01-27 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-01-28 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-01-29 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-01-30 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-01-31 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-02-01 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 2023-02-02 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Just another option using an ad-hoc tally/numbers table and a conditional aggregation. Then finally, the window function `sum() over()` to calculate the running NET.

You may notice I used `TOP 1000` for the numbers table.  Feel free to adjust to a more reasonable number (*but be generous ... leave some wiggle room*)

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
Select CalendarDate  
      ,CountOpen    = sum( case when [DateOpen]  =CalendarDate then 1 else 0 end)
      ,CountClosed  = sum( case when [DateClosed]=CalendarDate then 1 else 0 end)
 From YourTable
 Join ( Select Top 1000 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2 ) B
   on N<=datediff(day,[DateOpen],coalesce([DateClosed],[DateOpen]))
 Cross Apply ( values (dateadd(day,N,[DateOpen])) ) C(CalendarDate)
 Group By CalendarDate
)
Select *
      ,Net = sum(CountOpen-CountClosed) over (order by CalendarDate)
 From  cte
 Order by CalendarDate
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! ....is there a trick to this? It does not recognize any of the column names as I type this out...using SQL Management Studio 18

Comment: @UnknownValue I see the issue.  Your sample data has [Date Open] with a space but your DML has none.   One moment

Comment: @UnknownValue Corrected.  Try it now

Comment: I am copying and pasting the table names as their are written in the actual table, just replacing the example column names with real column names

Comment: Not clear on what you are doing, but here is a dbFiddle.   They seem to be having an issue, but it works the same under the Linux install:  https://dbfiddle.uk/G0CtnHCK